# My wpf app stops running when async processes start

Tags: c#, wpf

So, my app worked with sync methods, but it stops as I use async methods.

This is a code in my class when object creates.

```
_isAdult = (DateСalculation.CalculateAgeAsync(DateOfBirth).Result >= 18);
_sunSign = DateСalculation.CalculateSunSignAsync(DateOfBirth).Result;
_chineseSign = DateСalculation.CalculateSunSignAsync(DateOfBirth).Result;
_isBirthday = DateСalculation.IsBirthdayAsync(DateOfBirth).Result;
```

And this is async methods.

```
public static class DateCalculation
{
    public static string CalculateSunSign(DateTime date){...}
    public static async Task<string> CalculateSunSignAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => CalculateSunSign(date));
    }

    public static string CalculateChineseSign(DateTime date) {...}
    public static async Task<string> CalculateChineseSignAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => CalculateChineseSign(date));
    }

    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime date) {...}
    public static async Task<int> CalculateAgeAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => CalculateAge(date));
    }

    public static bool IsBirthday(DateTime date) {...}
    public static async Task<bool> IsBirthdayAsync(DateTime date)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => IsBirthday(date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever using *async*, *await*, you should not use `.Result` (unless you have to) because it blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

So change the code as per below:

```cs
_isAdult = (await (DateСalculation.CalculateAgeAsync(DateOfBirth)) >= 18);
_sunSign = await DateСalculation.CalculateSunSignAsync(DateOfBirth);
_chineseSign = await DateСalculation.CalculateSunSignAsync(DateOfBirth);
_isBirthday = await DateСalculation.IsBirthdayAsync(DateOfBirth);
```

Checking [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) documentation can help you.

Comment: AFAIK Calling `.Result` bare is a hidden deadlock